# ip change during page load

Tags: apache, http, networking, browser, f5

What happens to n xhr calls that happen during page load and ip changes in between?

e.g.

```
/mysite/index.html  (ip: 10.x.x.12) <-- http connection 1
/mysite/api/call-1  (ip: 10.x.x.12) <-- http connection 2
/mysite/api/call-2  (ip: 10.x.x.43) *<-- ip change (http conn 3)
```

Since each xhr has different connections.
Notice that the 3rd connection has ip change.

is this possible? Would any browsers stop creating such connection (connection 3 in the above example)

I am debugging a 504 timeout issue that can't see in any logs in any of the layers (e.g. apache, app). I don't have access to all the logs at all the layers e.g. F5 but F5 should not send 504 I believe. Any thoughts?

Comment: That would now be an invalid TCP connection, and TCP should send a RST killing the non-existent connection. A TCP connection is identified but both the source and destination IP and TCP addresses, and changing one of those four values identifies a different connection. TCP sends a RST for a segment received for a connection that has not been properly initialized with the three-way handshake.

Comment: @RonMaupin what if the call-2 was a new connection. If the ip changed it would be a new connection.

Comment: You need to read _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html)_. It explains how TCP works. A connection is identified by both the source and destination IP and TCP addresses, but it consists of much more, e.g. a connection tracks window sizes sequence numbers that start with a random number when the connection is initialized, and receiving a segment with a sequence number outside the window results in TCP sending a RST and killing the connection. Everything need to match the connection parameters.

Comment: browsers create new connections as the number of requests for the xhr calls - TCP is for each connection

Comment: Yes, an application can create multiple connections, but receiving segments with the wrong connection information results in RST, connection killed. You cannot change any of the four values that identify a connection without killing the connection. That has nothing to do with multiple connections. That means you cannot send what you want to do, changing a value that identifies a connection, without receiving a RST because it would represent a different connection that has not been properly initialized.